# Is there an event or other way to handle the user first ever message to the bot on the Facebook Messenger Platform?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chat, facebook-chatbot

I have set up a welcome message to my chat bot on Facebook Messenger platform. Now I want to know when the user sends it's first ever message and handle this special case (typically by getting some more info about the user and storing it for future use and not query facebook graph API on every message).

Is there a special event when the user clicks the "Get started" CTA on messenger ? Any other easy way (except storing some data identifying the user myself) ?

Comment: I never said that I want to query my storage every time I get a message.

Comment: don't know if the bot would send the message delivery callbacks for the welcome messages when registering the `message_deliveries` event in your webhook, try it!

Comment: There's a difference between sending the very first message and pressing the "Get Started" button. You don't get any notification for the "Get Started" button. It will directly show your welcome screen to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be solved now with the latest additions from facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button

So you can just enter the specific payload for the "Get Started button" and act accordingly.